# Install jenkins slave on Windows (AWS) gives java heap allocation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, chef-infra, winrm

I am using the [jenkins cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins) to set up a windows slave on AWS. Locally (vagrant on virtualbox), it converges correctly, but when provisioning a new machine on aws using chef-provisioning and the fog driver, I run into the following error:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'jenkins_windows_slave[build-slave]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "java" -jar "C:\chef\cache/jenkins-cli.jar" -s http://10.0.0.5:8080 groovy C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/groovy20150312-536-1d2hoy4 ----
STDOUT: Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to allocate 61440KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 1966080KB heap.
STDERR: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
---- End output of "java" -jar "C:\chef\cache/jenkins-cli.jar" -s http://10.0.0.5:8080 groovyC:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/groovy20150312-536-1d2hoy4 ----
Ran "java" -jar "C:\chef\cache/jenkins-cli.jar" -s http://10.0.0.5:8080 groovy C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/groovy20150312-536-1d2hoy4 returned 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_jenkins/recipes/slave_windows.rb

53: jenkins_windows_slave node['jenkins']['node']['name'] do
54:   remote_fs node['jenkins']['node']['remote_fs'] # jenkins workspace items stored here
55:   group     node['jenkins']['node']['group']     # Group with access to remote_fs
56:   user      node['jenkins']['node']['user']      # user the service runs under (and remote_fs owner)
57:   password  node['jenkins']['node']['password']  # for user running the service
58:   labels    node['jenkins']['node']['labels']    # labels on Jenkins master
59:   action    :create
60: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/xyz_jenkins/recipes/slave_windows.rb:53:in `from_file'

jenkins_windows_slave("build-slave") do
action [:create]
retries 0
retry_delay 2
default_guard_interpreter :default
declared_type :jenkins_windows_slave
cookbook_name "xyz_jenkins"
recipe_name "slave_windows"
remote_fs "C:\\jenkins"
group "Everyone"
user "jenkins"
password "apasswordhere"
labels ["builder", "windows"]
slave_name "build-slave"
end
```

**chef-provisioning's stack trace:**

```
U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provisioning/transport/winrm.rb:144:in `error!'
  U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provisioning/machine/basic_machine.rb:31:in `block in execute'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider.rb:180:in `converge_by'
  U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provisioning/chef_provider_action_handler.rb:54:in `perform_action'
  U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provisioning/machine/basic_machine.rb:29:in `execute'
  U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provisioning/convergence_strategy/install_msi.rb:49:in`block (2 levels) in converge'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:268:in `open_stream'
  U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provisioning/chef_provider_action_handler.rb:59:in `open_stream'
  U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provisioning/convergence_strategy/install_msi.rb:46:in`block in converge'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:268:in `open_stream'
  U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provisioning/chef_provider_action_handler.rb:59:in `open_stream'
  U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provisioning/convergence_strategy/install_msi.rb:45:in`converge'
  U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provisioning/machine/basic_machine.rb:21:in `converge'
  U:/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-0.19/lib/chef/provider/machine.rb:62:in `block in <class:Machine>'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/lwrp_base.rb:60:in `instance_eval'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/lwrp_base.rb:60:in `recipe_eval_with_update_check'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider/lwrp_base.rb:45:in `block in action'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider.rb:145:in `run_action'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource.rb:582:in `run_action'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:83:in `block in execute_each_resource'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:81:in `execute_each_resource'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:315:in `converge'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:400:in `block in run'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:399:in `catch'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:399:in `run'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:243:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:220:in `block in run_chef_client'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:38:in `with_server_connectivity'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:201:in `run_chef_client'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:355:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:345:in `loop'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:345:in `interval_run_chef_client'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:335:in `run_application'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/chef-client:52:in `load'
  C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/chef-client:52:in `<main>'
```

**chef run stack trace**

```
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:278:in `invalid!'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:265:in `error!'
C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/jenkins/libraries/_executor.rb:82:in `execute!'
C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/jenkins/libraries/_executor.rb:127:in `groovy!'
C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/jenkins/libraries/slave.rb:315:in `current_slave'
C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/jenkins/libraries/slave.rb:129:in `load_current_resource'
C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/jenkins/libraries/slave_jnlp.rb:52:in `load_current_resource'
C:/chef/cache/cookbooks/jenkins/libraries/slave_windows.rb:62:in `load_current_resource'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider.rb:128:in `run_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource.rb:561:in `run_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:83:in `block in execute_each_resource'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:81:in `execute_each_resource'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:331:in `block in converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:326:in `catch'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:326:in `converge'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:345:in `converge_and_save'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:448:in `run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:253:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:230:in `block in run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:38:in `with_server_connectivity'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:213:in `run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:392:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:382:in `loop'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:382:in `interval_run_chef_client'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:372:in `run_application'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:60:in `run'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:64:in `load'
C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client:64:in `<main>'
```

I have tried different versions of the chef-client to resolve the issue, but that did not help. I'm not sure if the problem is with the jenkins recipe, chef-provisioning, or what.

Because the jenkins recipes work on a local vagrant machine running the same OS (win 2012 R2), I'm thinking this *may* be a problem with chef-provisioning-fog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem is with WinRM. The current version of the [chef-provisioning-fog](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-fog) driver hard-codes the AWS user data in order to set up WinRM on the machine. Part of this setup sets the per-shell memory limit to 300MB, and the java command executed by the jenkins recipe wants to reserve 2GB of heap; hence the fatal error.

The short-term fix is to up the per-shell WinRM limit from 300MB to 2GB:

```
set-item wsman:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048
```

With chef-provisioning, put this resource after getting the machine ready and before converging:

```
machine_execute 'set-item wsman:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048' do
  machine "jenkins-win-slave-#{i}"
end
```

Long term, hopefully [the issue](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-fog/issues/83) is resolved and user data can be customized to set up winrm however the user sees fit.